# Specific CSS Menu layout

Tags: html, css, menu

I am dealing with some web development issues and want to know how I can achieve [this specific menu](http://www.michaelkeutel.de/Layout.png) layout in HTML, CSS, Javascript.
When hovering over "Design" or "Hintergründe" the main area changes and shows the content. My problem is the border, the outline that changes when the active menu point is changed. So I would take 2 div containers for "Design" and "Hintergründe" with borders at left, top and right (no bottom). And the main area has to be a div with borders itself. How can I achieve the mising party of the border where menu-choice and main area blend one into another?

By the way: Are those costum (thin) scrollbars possible in HTML for div containers?

Thx in advance
All the best
Michael

Comment: you could set the top-margin of content div to -1 and then set the bottom border for the menu point to the background-color of the div

Comment: The custom scrollbars are possible with the use of javascript/jquery. Take a look here http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tab that you click on has the same background colour as the content area, and it has `margin-bottom:-1px` and a `z-index` to place it over the content. This makes the background cover up the content area's border, producing the effect you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

MichiMichbeck gave a good answer regarding the tabs.

For the thin scrollbar try one of the many javascript/jquery plugins that are available.
One example is: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

You can also change the scrollbar for webkit browser in CSS: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/. But the javasript solution would probably be preferred.

Comment: The thin scrollbars can be done with nanoscroller: http://jamesflorentino.github.com/nanoScrollerJS/